# How can the outermost electrons in silicon be 2s and 2p electrons?

Tags: electronic-configuration, erratum

My book says the number of outermost electrons in silicon is $4$. Yes, right. But then it says those are $\ce{2s}$ and $\ce{2p}$ electrons. The electronic configuration of silicon is $\ce{1s^2  2s^2  2p^6  3s^2  3p^2}$.

How are the outermost electrons $\ce{2s}$ and $\ce{2p}$ electrons. Those belong to third shell.

Then it says the maximum number of electrons in the outermost shell is $8$. Correct. But then it says those  are $\ce{2s + 6p}$ electrons. How?

Comment: The electron configuration you give is correct, 2 electrons each in 3s and 3p orbitals. Sometimes this is written in shorthand as $\ce{(Ne) 3s^2 3p^2}$ where the (Ne) represents Neon's configuration. I suspect that there is /are typos in your text. (btw, don't hate Chemistry: you can be interested in all sorts of subjects while still having favourites)

Comment: Please add citations to your post, it is not helpful to anyone further if the source of this is unclear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The book means to say that there are 2 electrons in the  $\mathrm{3s}$ subshell and and 2 electrons in the  $\mathrm{3p}$ subshell. You can see this in the electron configuration as

> $\mathrm{...3s^2 3p^2}$

and that the maximum configuration has 2 electrons in the  $\mathrm{3s}$ subshell and 6 electrons in the  $\mathrm{3p}$ subshell which would be

> $\mathrm{...3s^2 3p^6}$

Answer (score 8):

Concur with this point:

"*$\ce{2s}$ and $\ce{2p}$ valence electrons*" is not the same thing as "*two $\ce{s}$ and two $\ce{p}$ valence electrons*".

Your book probably used the latter, but you interpreted it as the former. Though, it is entirely possible that the book wrote it the way you *say* it had, but unless you quote that particular line and cite the book (as Mod. Martin pointed out), it will be impossible to ascertain that.

So for the record, silicon *does* have a valence configuration of $$\ce{3s^{2} 3p^{2}}$$

You must be attentive while reading such things ;-)

---

Now for the second part of your question,

> Then it says the maximum number of electrons in the outermost shell is $\ce{8}$

Well, technically, the maximum possible number of electrons in the outermost shell (which is $\ce{n = 3}$ in this case) is $\ce{18}$ and **not** $\ce{8}$.

That's because the third shell is constituted by $\ce{s, p, d}$ subshells. (Granted, ground-state silicon doesn't *use* those $\ce{d}$ orbitals, but your post only mentions "*outermost shell*", so I thought mentioning this should be of help)

The third shell would therefore have one $\ce{s}$ orbital (holds 2 electrons), three $\ce{p}$ orbitals (holds 6 electrons) and five $\ce{d}$ orbitals (holds 10 electrons). So,

$$\mathrm{ 2 + 6 + 10 = 18 }$$